# How can I implement a config service in an angular app with no app.module file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-services, environment-variables

My ultimate goal is to store/manage environment variables like backend URL in a scalable and maintainable way. Initially, I was using the standard angular environments folders with environment.production.ts, environment.development.ts, etc... This worked for development but the problem (as I'm sure most of you know) is that all the build artifacts associated with that configuration don't get deployed with the rest of the code and the app has to be rebuilt when configuration changes from dev to production, for example.

I've done a lot of reading and learned that a better solution is to create a config.json file and use a config service to inject the values in the config everywhere they're needed at runtime. The problem is that all these implementations involve an app.module file which I don't have--I'm working on an angular app with standalone components so there's no central app.module file in which to integrate a config.service with APP_INITIALIZER.

Right now, I'm just using static references to config.json which, of course, is very problematic and a config service is needed. Is there a way to integrate my config service with the bootstrapApplication() function in main.ts? What would this look like?

Comment: Please you have multiple question, and you give context that dont help. What is your question ?

Comment: @Tim Per my title, my question is how to get values in a config.json file injected in my code without any app.module file in which to integrate a config service.

Comment: @22Fonzie did you find a resolution to this as I'm having the same issue. I have a config.json file and the values are being replaced at time of deployment but the default values are still being used at runtime